# Import CSV data to fields in MySQL Database

Tags: php, html, mysql, csv

I am trying to upload a CSV file which contains the fields stated in the link below [see CSV example] via a web form. The user can browse their computer by clicking the upload button, select their CSV file and then click upload which then imports the CSV data into the database in their corresponding fields. At the moment when the user uploads their CSV file, the row is empty and doesn't contain any of the data that the CSV file contains. Is there a way i could solve this so that the data inside the CSV file gets imported to the database and placed in its associating fields?

**CSV example:** 

http://i754.photobucket.com/albums/xx182/rache_R/Screenshot2014-04-10at145431_zps80a42938.png

**uploads.php**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>MySQL file upload example</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <form action="upload_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="uploaded_file"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload file">
    </form>
    <p>
        <a href="list_files.php">See all files</a>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

**upload_file.php**

```
    <?php
// Check if a file has been uploaded
if(isset($_FILES['uploaded_file'])) {
    // Make sure the file was sent without errors
    if($_FILES['uploaded_file']['error'] == 0) {
        // Connect to the database
        $dbLink = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'vario007', 'spineless');
        if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            die("MySQL connection failed: ". mysqli_connect_error());
        }

        // Gather all required data
        $filedata= file_get_contents($_FILES  ['uploaded_file']['tmp_name']); //this imports the entire file.

        // Create the SQL query
        $query = "
            INSERT INTO `Retail` (
                `date`, `order_ref`, `postcode`, `country`, `quantity`, `packing_price`, `dispatch_type`, `created`
            )
            VALUES (
                '{$date}', '{$order_ref}', '{$postcode}', '{$country}', '{$quantity}', '{$packing_price}', '{$dispatch_type}', NOW()
            )";

        // Execute the query
        $result = $dbLink->query($query);


        // Check if it was successfull
        if($result) {
            echo 'Success! Your file was successfully added!';
        }
        else {
            echo 'Error! Failed to insert the file'
               . "<pre>{$dbLink->error}</pre>";
        }
    }
    else {
        echo 'An error accured while the file was being uploaded. '
           . 'Error code: '. intval($_FILES['uploaded_file']['error']);
    }

    // Close the mysql connection
    $dbLink->close();
}
else {
    echo 'Error! A file was not sent!';
}

// Echo a link back to the main page
echo '<p>Click <a href="welcome.php">here</a> to go back</p>';
?>
```

Comment: please more description for you want insert a csv data or csv file

Comment: remember you are inserting stuff like $date in a double-quoted string. that string will be parsed, the variables will be replaced, and php will complain in strict mode if no such variables exist (i say this because i don't see the variables as declared).

Comment: is there a way to use positional parameters in the query instead of varible names? like `... values (?, ?, ?, ...)`, you could pass an array as argument, and positional parameters would be filled position-by-position from the array

Comment: @LuisMasuelli im still learning the ropes with PHP, what do you mean by positional parameters?

Comment: See this example: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php - you could call it as $dbLink->prepare. After that, you `bind` your arguments as in the example. FINALLY you must EXECUTE the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
<?php
if(isset($_FILES['uploaded_file'])) {
    if($_FILES['uploaded_file']['error'] == 0) {
        $dbLink = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'vario007', 'spineless');
        if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            die("MySQL connection failed: ". mysqli_connect_error());
        }

        $file = $_FILES  ['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'];
        $handle = fopen($file, "r");
        $row = 1;
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ",","'")) !== FALSE)
        {
            if($row == 1)
            {
                // skip the first row   
            }
            else
            {
                //csv format data like this 
                //$data[0] = date
                //$data[1] = order_ref
                //$data[2] = postcode
                //$data[3] = country
                //$data[4] = quantity
                //$data[5] = packing_price
                //$data[6] = dispatch_type

                $query = "
                INSERT INTO `Retail` (
                `date`, `order_ref`, `postcode`, `country`, `quantity`, `packing_price`, `dispatch_type`, `created`
                )
                VALUES (
                '".$data[0]."', '".$data[1]."', '".$data[2]."', '".$data[3]."', '".$data[4]."', '".$data[5]."', '".$data[6]."', NOW()
                )";
                $result = $dbLink->query($query);


                 // Check if it was successfull
                if($result) {
                    echo 'Success! Your file was successfully added!';
                }
                else {
                    echo 'Error! Failed to insert the file'
                    . "<pre>{$dbLink->error}</pre>";
                 }
            }
            $row++;
        }



    }
    else {
        echo 'An error accured while the file was being uploaded. '
           . 'Error code: '. intval($_FILES['uploaded_file']['error']);
    }

    // Close the mysql connection
    $dbLink->close();
}
else {
    echo 'Error! A file was not sent!';
}

// Echo a link back to the main page
echo '<p>Click <a href="welcome.php">here</a> to go back</p>';
?>
```

`fgetcsv()` in third argument in separator to you want to save in csv file. Ex: comma,semicolon or etc.

Comment: try a changes i hope this is usefull

Comment: I have tried using your code. It adds however many rows there are in the CSV file but the fields are still blank @Mehul

Comment: are they not the same thing? :S @Mehul

Comment: this is what the database looks like after i upload the file @Mehul http://i754.photobucket.com/albums/xx182/rache_R/Screenshot2014-04-11at095604_zps922c64a1.png

Comment: sorry i have one mistack a in insert a query variable $row not ok change a varible $data

Comment: oh great thank you. The data dumps all the data into one column and is separated by commas, would i need to explode the string? @Mehul

Comment: to change fgetcsv() this function in third argument semicolon to comma

Answer (score 0):

```
function csv_to_array($filename='', $delimiter=',')
{
    if(!file_exists($filename) || !is_readable($filename))
        return FALSE;

   $header = NULL;
   $data = array();
   if (($handle = fopen($filename, 'r')) !== FALSE)
   {
     while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, $delimiter)) !== FALSE)
     {
        if(!$header)
            $header = $row;
        else
            $data[] = array_combine($header, $row);
     }
     fclose($handle);
   }
   return $data;
}



$filedata= csv_to_array($_FILES  ['uploaded_file']['tmp_name']);

foreach($filedata as $data)
{
    $sql = "INSERT into table SET value1='".$data['value1']."'......";
}
```